# Converting SVG created with D3js to PNG

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, svg, png

I have some charts created with D3js which I want to convert to a PNG-image through JavaScript so users can download the chart.

I have seen solutions that convert the SVG to a canvas and convert the canvas to an image. This will not work for me because the SVG uses classes to style the elements (which is something I'd rather not change because of mantainability), which causes the whole canvas to become black with very thick lines.

Is it possible to convert the SVG-charts to PNG directly?

The page is inside a Ruby on Rails project so it doesn't have to be a pure JavaScript solution, but I'd prefer to do this with JavaScript so I can also implement it in other projects.

Comment: Sorry I haven't done anything with SVG yet, so this answer could be nonsense :).

Are you saying that by using classes and not inline styles that things get screwed up when converting to canvas?

In which case, is it not a matter of programatically apply the styles from the css class before converting to canvas?

Comment: When I added this question 2 moths ago, that was indeed the problem. I already implemented a solution similair to what you suggested. The problem I ran into after that is that most browsers won't render the generated canvas/PNG correctly. This results into elements missing and/or the image becomming black. A problem I ran into for IE is that I cannot pass data-uri's larger than 2,048 characters, so I cannot pass the whole uri to present it for downloading (not really question related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display your svg within a canvas, you first have to convert it using a parser/renderer utility such as http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

(code adapted from: Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser)

```
// the canvg call that takes the svg xml and converts it to a canvas
canvg('canvas', $("svg").html());

// the canvas calls to output a png
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: Hmm, I have two questions about this: first: Do I have to implement all 3 libraries (rgbcolor, stackblur, canvg)?, second: I noticed the canvg.js file is quite large. doe you know any smaller libraries? or is it possible to identify only the nescesarry methods? I ask this because an RoR application loads all JS-files on first load, so another large library (we already have a lot of JS) would make it slower on the first load.

Comment: Although this is not my "perfect" solution, it does work. So I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Does canvg solution works with NodeJS to convert SVG to PNG at server side? I tried with svg2png but it didn't run well on windows7